# Integrating ResKit into existing Core Data app

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have an existing Core Data app to which I would now like to add REST support for remote storage of my objects. I have decided to integrate RestKit because that seems like (by far) the most mature framework for REST support, but am somewhat unclear on the Core Data integration part of it.

Since I have a working app so far, I don't want to completely hand over all the Core Data work to RestKit, and yet it seems like I cannot tell RestKit to map NSManagedObjects unless I also let it manage the object store. I come to this conclusion because the RKManagedObjectMapping class requires a RKManagedObjectStore when setting the mapping for a managed class. And RKManagedObjectStore seems to want control of the database file through its various initializers.

Is this correct?

Ideally, I would like to maintain my local store just like I am doing, and add "remoting" capability via RestKit. The only way that comes to mind is to have remote variants of my Core Data classes, and use them to proxy between the two models.

I can't help but think I am missing something. Any pointers or sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it RestKit does not take over the management. They just wrap it and adds convenience methods to make setting up and getting to the managed objects easier. I tried it with my data on the simulator past couple of weeks and have no issues. I have yet to deploy this change to the device but soon. So let's suppose you already have an RKObjectMananger initialized.
 Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Can you maybe share a code snippet to show how you got it working in your app?